# Starting load fallback graphics devices [fail] - at the boot time

Tags: 12.04, boot

I had some problem when Ubuntu is booting.

After BIOS windows it trows this mistake:

> Starting load fallback graphics devices    [fail]

After this I see terminal with suggestions to enter login and password.

I couldn't figure out why this happen?

Here is my [boot.log](http://paste2.org/Cv3ZLGdN)

It was started after I restarted PC.

I have NVidia video card.

By the way it has another trouble at `/var/log/boot.log`:

```
Starting vmware services\:
vm monitor          [fail]
vm communication... [fail]
vm socket family    [fail]
```

But I deleted all vmware product. And now this message is discard.

**- How to solve this trouble?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem. After upgrading the nvidia drivers, it solved it.

1. remove the existing nvidia driver :

   `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current`
2. updrage to the new driver: (follow this link)

   http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-The-Latest-Nvidia-Driver-on-Ubuntu-12-04-295542.shtml

   Here are commands I followed.

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

   `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

Comment: It will be nice if you mention a resume of those instructions from the link here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  I actually created it myself by installing nvidia-current (which is recommended by Chit in his answer) when trying to solve another problem.

I eventually discovered that nvidia drivers more recent than the 173.14.xx series would not work with my old card.  I found the correct legacy drivers here:

http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html

So this is what I did:

```
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/173.14.39/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1.run
chmod 755 NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1.run
sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1.run
```

Rebooted and it worked!